# Работа с буфером обмена через WinApi

Tags: c#, winapi, кодировка

Доброго времени суток.
Я тут работаю с буфером обмена.
Так, как `Clipboard.SetText(<Текст>)` отказывается работать (`COMException`) то пришлось писать свой велосипед:

```
unsafe public static class Clipboard
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int OpenClipboard(
        IntPtr hWndNewOwner
    );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int CloseClipboard();

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int EmptyClipboard();

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData(
        uint uFormat
    );

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetClipboardData(
        uint uFormat,
        IntPtr hMem
    );

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(
        IntPtr hMem
    );

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GlobalUnlock(
        IntPtr hMem
    );

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr GlobalAlloc(
        uint uFlags,
        ulong dwBytes
    );

    [DllImport("msvcrt", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int wcscpy(char* str1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]StringBuilder str2);

    private const uint CF_TEXT = 1;
    private const uint GMEM_DDESHARE = 8192;

    public static void SetText(string strText)
    {
        if (OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero) != 0)
        {
            IntPtr hgBuffer;
            char* chBuffer;
            EmptyClipboard();
            hgBuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, 2 * Convert.ToUInt64(strText.Length + 1)); // 2 = sizeof(wchar_t) -- C++; sizeof(char) -- C#
            chBuffer = (char*)GlobalLock(hgBuffer);
            wcscpy(chBuffer, new StringBuilder(strText));
            GlobalUnlock(hgBuffer);
            SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hgBuffer);
            CloseClipboard();
        }
    }

    public static string GetText()
    {
        if (OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero) != 0)
        {
            IntPtr hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            char* chBuffer = (char*)GlobalLock(hData);
            string strResult = new string(chBuffer);
            GlobalUnlock(hData);
            CloseClipboard();
            return strResult;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Но если ложить текст через свой метод, а затем извлекать через свой метод, то все работает, но если я копирую текст в другой проге (например, в браузере), а затем извлекаю его из буфера обмена через свой метод, то отображаются кракозябры:

[image]

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Браузер копирует в одной кодировке, а вы читаете в другой.

Все-таки вам лучше бы разобраться в причинах COMException, чем писать убогие велосипеды.

Comment: Ошибка при вызове OpenClipboard(Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800401D0(CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN)) - как бороться не знаю(

Comment: > CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN

А погуглить? По всей видимости, какое-то приложение (может даже ваше) уже открыло буфер обмена, но еще не закрыло. Класс Clipboard, как вы понимаете, - обертка над WinAPI. Ваша обертка будет фейлиться точно так же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена путем замены `CF_TEXT` на `CF_UNICODETEXT`, равное 13.